# Is there a way to detect `\left` in front of macros?

Tags: math-mode, macros, delimiters

Is there a way to have a macro optionally prefixed with `\left` or `\right` and have it expand differently depending on that? For example, have `\bra{x}` expand to `\langle x |`, but `\left\bra{x}` to `\left\langle x \middle|`? Extra bonus if it works also with explicit size prefixes, giving that size to both `\langle` and `|`.

Some examples of what you could do with such macros:

Assuming a corresponding `\ket` macro, one could then write e.g.

```
\left\bra{x} \frac{\hat p}{m} \right\ket{x}
```

and have it expand to

```
\left\langle x \middle| \frac{\hat p}{m} \middle| x \right\rangle
```

i.e. the size of the brackets would depend on both the arguments and what's in between. On the other hand,

```
\bra{x} \frac{\hat p}{m} \ket{x}
```

would just expand to

```
\langle x | \frac{\hat p}{m} | \rangle
```

that is, without extension. Since there would be exactly one `\left` in the expansion of the `\left`-prefixed macro, and exactly one `\right` in the expansion of the `\right`-prefixed macro, one could also combine it with normal delimiters (including the "pseudo-delimiter" `.`). So for example,

```
\left\langle{x^2}\right.
```

would expand only according to what is inside the argument.

(Note: I am aware of the braket package, so no need to point that out. Note that it doesn't the `\left`/`\right` thing either.)

Comment: Did you know that $(x)$ is equivalent in appearance to `$\left(x\right)$`? Therefore, you can use `\left` and `\right` even if the contents doesn't require the delimiters to expand.

Comment: @Werner: The x was an example. It could be something larger. But then, note that the corresponding `\right` is not in the macro, so something *outside* that macro would also influence the size, e.g. (assuming a corresponding `\ket`): `\left\bra{x}\frac{\hat{p}}{m}\right\ket{x}` would give quite large parens despite the argument of `\bra` and `\ket` being single letters.

Comment: @Werner: I just note that I had a mistake in my post (I forgot the `{x}` in the `\left` version), maybe that led you in the wrong direction. I've now added it (I also corrected another mistake (`\left` instead of `\mid`), but that didn't change anything I said in my other comment).

Comment: I find the question requires a little more explanation. For example, `\left` requires a `\right` partner while in your example you want it to expand to `\left...\mid`. Also `\mid` is a symbol and not a macro to extend the delimiter `|`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  It would be very helpful if you would compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem and provides a test case.

Comment: @Werner: Sorry about the `\mid`, it should of course be `\middle`. I'll fix it immediately. About the `\right`: That is supposed to be provided outside the macro, as in the example I've given in my previous comment. I'll add an usage example in the question to clarify.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Thanks for the welcome. I hope my text is now clearer. I cannot provide a minimally working example because my point is exactly that I don't know how (or even if) I can do it. If I could provide a MWE, the question would be pointless.

Comment: Not sure why you think it would be pointless. A MWE should clearly illustrate what you are looking for and the various ways that you want it to work. If there is particular syntax you just add it as a comment if it won't compile with that.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Actually I provided that even before my first edit: I provided the two macro uses, and what they should expand to. After my edit I also added three examples of how the macros would actually be used, again with expansion. I don't know what else I could provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice problem without a real solution, I'm afraid; unless one redefines `\left`, which I'm not willing to do. Werner's definition is quite safe and might be extended to `\bigl` and company. But this doesn't make it more manageable than a syntax with an optional argument.

The following one works, but has a big drawback: if `\bra` is found in a group formed by another `\left`, everything will die horribly.

```
\let\TeXmiddle\middle

\def\bra#1{\langle#1
  \ifnum\currentgrouptype=16
    \neutralizeright
  \else
      \neutralizemiddle
  \fi}

\def\neutralizeright{%
  \def\middle##1{\TeXmiddle##1}%
  \let\rightket\right
  \let\right\relax
  \aftergroup\neutralizeright}
\def\neutralizemiddle{\let\middle\relax}
\let\rightket\relax
\def\ket#1{#1\rightket\rangle}

$\bra{x}\middle|y\middle|\ket{z}$

$\left\bra{x} \middle| \frac{a}{b} \middle| \right\ket{z}$
```

The `\middle` in the first formula is optional as it does nothing. However, as I said before, something like

```
$\left( \bra{x}|y|\ket{z} \right)$
```

will die. The conditional `\ifnum\currentgrouptype=16` checks whether we are in a group initiated by `\left`. Since `\left` expands the following token in order to find a delimiter, `\bra` is expanded after it and the business can go on. But there's no way to know *when* `\left` has been opened as the third example shows.

I would prefer a syntax such as

```
\bra{x} | y | \ket{z}
\bra[\left]{x} | y | \ket{z}
\bra[\big]{x} | y | \ket{z}
```

that could be defined in a rather straightforward way. Here is a way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`|
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\braketmiddle}
\edef\pipedel{\delimiter\the\delcode`|}
\mathchardef\pipechar\mathcode`|

\newcommand{\bra}[2][]{\begingroup
  \mathcode`\|=\string"8000
  #1\langle
  \csname @bra\string#1ket@\endcsname#2}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{%
  #1\braketright\rangle\endgroup}
\expandafter\def\csname @braket@\endcsname{%
  \def\braketmiddle{\pipechar}
  \def\braketright{}
}
\expandafter\def\csname @bra\string\left ket@\endcsname{%
  \def\braketmiddle{\middle\pipedel}
  \def\braketright{\right}
  \expandafter\aftergroup\csname @bra\string\left ket@\endcsname
}
\expandafter\def\csname @bra\string\bigl ket@\endcsname{%
  \def\braketmiddle{\big\pipedel}
  \def\braketright{\bigr}
}
\expandafter\def\csname @bra\string\Bigl ket@\endcsname{%
  \def\braketmiddle{\Big\pipedel}
  \def\braketright{\Bigr}
}
\expandafter\def\csname @bra\string\biggl ket@\endcsname{%
  \def\braketmiddle{\bigg\pipedel}
  \def\braketright{\biggr}
}
\expandafter\def\csname @bra\string\Biggl ket@\endcsname{%
  \def\braketmiddle{\Bigg\pipedel}
  \def\braketright{\Biggr}
}

\begin{document}

%\tracingmacros=1 \tracingonline=1
$\bra{x} | \bra{1}|2|\ket{3} y | \ket{z}$

$\bra[\left]{x} | \bra{1}|2|\ket{3}\dfrac{y}{2} | \ket{z}$

$\bra[\bigl]{x} | y | \ket{z}$

$\bra[\Bigl]{x} | y | \ket{z}$

$\bra[\biggl]{x} | y | \ket{z}$

$\bra[\Biggl]{x} | y | \ket{z}$

\end{document}
```

This even allows nesting.

Some comments about the second solution. The syntax is

```
\bra[<size>]{x} | y | \ket{z}
```

where the `y |` part is optional. In order to process correctly the `|` character we'll assign it `\mathcode"8000` which means that it will behave like an active character. So first of all we define the active version of `|` as `\braketmiddle`, which in turn will be defined in different ways according to the `<size>` argument. Its default definition (no `<size>` specification) is `\pipechar` which is defined by `` \mathchardef\pipechar=\mathcode`| `` that is, to be like the ordinary `|`. So `|` in the braket will give a simple vertical bar.

When a size specification has been given, `\braketmiddle` will become `\middle\pipedel` or `\big\pipedel` and similarly for the others; `\middle`, `\big` and company want to see a delimiter after them so we have defined

```
\edef\pipedel{\delimiter\the\delcode`|}
```

Each character has a `\delcode` (for most of them it's zero, meaning that they are *not* delimiters). The `|` character has one and we access it with `` \the\delcode`| `` (we couldn't say `\middle|`, because we have assigned the special mathcode to `|`). Thus in our context `\middle\pipedel` is the same as an ordinary `\middle|` and the same for `\big` and company.

Similarly each `<size>` specification defines a meaning for `\braketright` that's put in front of the closing `\rangle`. There's a subtle point here in the case when `<size>` is `\left`. When TeX finds `\left...\middle` it opens a group  with `\left` and *closes* it at `\middle` to reopen it until finding the next `\middle` or `\right`. So we have to carry over the redefinitions we made to the next group and this is achieved by the strange `\aftergroup`. But this would take too far.

Comment: Again, a nice solution. Definitely a +1. However I've got a problem now: I can only select one of the answers. But both would have earned it: Your first solution has the exact syntax, but is not robust, while Werner's solution is robust, but slightly modifies the syntax. Your second solution looks also quite interesting; however I don't really understand it. Could you please add some short explanation of those `\delcode`, `\mathcode` and `\string`? I think I might be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation. I've now decided to make your answer the accepted one; however want to stress again that actually both answers would have deserved it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to use a (marginally) modified version of `\left` and `\right`, you could activate a toggle (a boolean true/false variable) to keep track of whether you're within a `\left`-`\right` scope.

In the MWE below, I've defined the toggle `insidedelim` that is `true` when you call `\left*` and becomes false after calling `\right*` - it is specific to the definition of `\bra` and `\ket`. Well, actually only `\ket`, but you could define other macros in a similar way as long as they duplicate the structure of `\ket` (which turns the toggle `insidedelim` off). The reason for this small alteration is because of your interest to make the delimiters extend based on contents outside it's scope. The regular `\left` and `\right` delimiter pairs still work as usual.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\newtoggle{insidedelim}% 
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{% \bar{<stuff>}
  \iftoggle{insidedelim}%
    {\oldleft\langle #1 \middle|}% \left*
    {\langle #1|}% \langle #1 \mid
}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{% \ket{<stuff>}
  \iftoggle{insidedelim}%
    {\middle| #1 \oldright\rangle\togglefalse{insidedelim}}% \right*
    {|#1 \rangle}% \mid #1 \rangle
}
\let\oldleft\left
\let\oldright\right
\RenewDocumentCommand{\left}{s}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}% starred/unstarred
    {\toggletrue{insidedelim}}% \left*
    {\oldleft}% \left
}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\right}{s}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}% starred/unstarred
    {}% \right*
    {\oldright}% \right
}
\begin{document}
$\langle x | \frac{\hat{p}}{m} | x \rangle$ \par \bigskip

$\bra{x} \frac{\hat{p}}{m} \ket{x}$ \par \bigskip

$\left\langle x \middle| \frac{\hat{p}}{m} \middle| x \right\rangle$ \par \bigskip

$\left*\bra{x} \frac{\hat{p}}{m} \right*\ket{x}$
\end{document}
```

Toggles and switching is provided by [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) while the advanced command definition interface is provided by [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse).

Comment: Nice, thank you. Definitely a +1. I'll wait some time if someone finds a solution without the star, if not, I'll also accept this answer as the right one.