# What's wrong with my braket macro?

Tags: math-mode, macros, delimiters

Based on egreg's alternate solution to my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35079/is-there-a-way-to-detect-left-in-front-of-macros) from which I learned the idea of making characters into macros, I've now defined a different syntax for bra-kets which I actually like even more. My macro *almost* works (although there's a bit of cargo cult programming going on here because I've copied some part of his solution which I didn't fully understand — the two lines beginning with `\begingroup\lccode` — in my macro and adapted them slightly; I suspect the problem is in there, because the rest I believe I understand sufficiently, thanks to egregs explanations to the other question).

Here's my macro definition:

```
\newcommand{\braket}[2][\middle]{\ensuremath{
\begingroup
\begingroup\lccode`~=`<
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#1\langle}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`|
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#1\pipedel}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`>
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#1\rangle}
\edef\pipedel{\delimiter\the\delcode`|}
\mathchardef\lt\mathcode`<
\mathchardef\pipechar\mathcode`|
\mathchardef\gt\mathcode`>
\mathcode`\<=\string"8000
\mathcode`\|=\string"8000
\mathcode`\>=\string"8000
\left.
#2
\right.
\endgroup
}}
```

The following usages all work as expected:

```
\braket{<\psi|\psi>}
\braket{<\psi|A|\psi>}
\braket{<\psi|\frac{p^2}{2m}|\psi>}
\braket[\Big]{<\alpha|\beta>}
\braket{|a \gt 0>}
\braket[]{<\psi|\frac{p^2}{2m}|\phi>}
```

(the last one simply disables automatic size adaption).

However, the following does *not* work correctly:

```
\braket{<0|1>}
```

It should give "〈0|1〉" but only gives "〈0〉".

So what's wrong with my macro, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You need something to "terminate" the macro `|`. `\bracket{<0| 1>}` produces the expected result.

Comment: Since there is the [braket](http://ctan.org/pkg/braket) package, this looks to me like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: In some sense it is. But on one hand, the braket package lacks flexibility (there are specific macros for each single case; if you have a case which was not provided by the author — like ketbra, or something like `\braket{||\psi>>}` — the braket package doesn't help you). On the other hand I don't learn anything by just using the package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that when TeX finds the active pipe, it expands it to

```
\delimiter 2532108
```

and a number following it will be incorporated to that code.

```
\mathchardef\lt\mathcode`<
\mathchardef\pipechar\mathcode`|
\mathchardef\gt\mathcode`>
\edef\pipedel{\delimiter\the\delcode`| }
\show\pipedel
\newcommand{\braket}[2][\middle]{
  \begingroup
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`<
    \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#1\langle}
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`|
    \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#1\pipedel\relax}
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`>
     \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#1\rangle}
  \mathcode`\<=\string"8000
  \mathcode`\|=\string"8000
  \mathcode`\>=\string"8000
  \mathopen{}\left.#2\right.\mathclose{}
  \endgroup
}
```

The `\relax` will avoid the problem. Also some parts are better outside the definition and `\ensuremath` is  not recommendable.

### Note on the `\lowercase` trick

When a character (of category code 11 or 12) is assigned mathcode `"8000` and is found in math mode, it is treated by TeX as if it were active (that is, like a macro) and a definition of it as an active character is needed.

A trick very commonly used is to exploit that `~` *is* active; when we want to give a meaning to the active `<`, there are two strategies. The first one is

```
{\catcode`<=\active \gdef<{something}}
```

which has some drawback: we are forced to execute it in advance and it is *global*. So we use a different strategy:

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`< \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{something}
```

How does this work? First of all, we open a group and in the group we tell TeX that the lowercase counterpart of `~` is `<`. Then we do `\lowercase`, which transforms *character tokens* into their lowercase counterpart (but leaving control sequences unaltered) and puts back the tokens as if they were there from the beginning. So TeX sees

```
\endgroup\def<{something}
```

(but `<` *is* active, as `\lowercase` doesn't change category codes). The `\endgroup` undoes the correspondence between `~` and `<` and the definition is performed. When, later, we say `` \mathcode`<=\string"8000 ``, the magic will happen (`\string` is a precaution against **babel** which might have made `"` into an active character).

Comment: Thank you, it works great! However: What's wrong with `\ensuremath`? Also, what do `\mathopen{}` and `\mathclose{}` do?

Comment: @celtschk `\mathopen{}` and `\mathclose{}` will avoid additional space inserted by the `\left` and `\right`; `\ensuremath` does really no good here: `\braket` *is* to be used in math formulas.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, avoiding extra space is a good idea here. BTW, I'm now wondering if it would make sense to move the `\relax` into the definition of `\pipedel`.

Comment: @celtschk It would be the same.

Comment: One thing I still don't understand is the definition method I copied from your code for the other question. I've already found out that it ultimately translates the `\def~` into `\def|` (or `\def<` or `\def>`) by declaring that character as lowercase equivalent of `~`; also I guess the `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` is there so that this lowercase definition does not persist. However what I don't understand is the idea behind this construction; it's obviously a trick, but I don't understand what it is for.

Comment: @celtschk I've little time now; check later for an expanded answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate explanation of the trick.